# Python: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace' "

Tags: python

I want to remove the letters from row[1] and row[2] or if they are empty put None. The loop places None works fine but when it get to the other loop if it encounters a None I get the error. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

```
a = [['something', 'G3535354', '33453421D'], ['something', '', 'R3848347']]

i = 0
char_no = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
for row in a:
  j = 0
  for col in row:
    if a[i][j] == '':
      a[i][j] = None
    j += 1
  for character in char_no:
    row[1] = row[1].replace(character, "")
    row[2] = row[2].replace(character, "")
  i += 1

print(a)
```

Comment: Tip: read up about `enumerate`. That avoids using extra lines such as `i = 0`, `i += 1` etc.

Comment: Also: the Python standard uses 4 spaces for indentation, not 2.

Comment: If you set an element of your nested list to `None`, it's not a string anymore. In the next loop, however, you use a string method on that element, namely, `.replace()`. So you'd get `None.replace(character, "")`. That will obviously fail.

Comment: Perhaps you should just switch the two inner loops around; see if that works. Because replacing characters in an empty string does nothing, thus, an empty string remains empty, and you can *later* replace it by `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the error you get when you run your code:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

As you already know, this happens in second loop, when you already placed `None` in your lists. You are trying to do `None.replace(character,"")` and it is not possible as `None` is not a string.

This will work:

```
if row[1]:
    row[1] = row[1].replace(character, "")
if row[2]:
    row[2] = row[2].replace(character, "")
```